# Shifting the new variable also shifts the old original one

Tags: javascript, arrays

How come with this

```
var prodataTemp = [];
prodataTemp = prodata;  
prodataTemp.shift();
```

both variable prodatTemp and prodata are shifted? I can see it in the console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a JavaScript object to another variable, will not copy the contents, but it make the left hand side variable, a reference to the right hand side expression. So,

```
var prodataTemp = [];
```

made `prodataTemp` refer an empty array and then

```
prodataTemp = prodata;
```

makes `prodataTemp` refer the same array object `prodata` was pointing to. (So, the old empty array is no more referenced by `prodataTemp`).

To actually make a copy<sup>**</sup>, use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), like this

```
prodataTemp = prodata.slice();
```

Now, `prodataTemp` refers to the copy of the array `prodata`, so that shifting one will not affect the other.

---

<sup>**</sup> - The copy made is just a shallow copy. So, if you have an array of arrays, then a new array will be created with all the references to the elements of the old array. So, mutating one array element will have its impact in the other as well.